# Openshift web console sessiontimeout

Tags: openshift, session-timeout

I want to set a timeout session for the openshift web console.

i found in `/etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml` something hat i suppose it works but not ==>

```
sessionConfig:sessionMaxAgeSeconds: 300
```

is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution :

in /etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml, modify this value :
accessTokenMaxAgeSeconds 
86400 by default

good use !

Ludo